# Get UML class diagram for IOS project by using Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using XCode 4.6 and i need to built a UML class diagram of my project how can i form this .Please if any body knows then kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle/). If you drop an Xcode project file onto its dock icon, it will generate a UML diagram.

Comment: I have already dowloaded but my Mac 10.7.5 not supported this soft ware